# Trying to get this loop to end after 20 lines

Tags: java, loops

Can someone assist me with getting this loop to stop after executing 20 times?

I have to get the code to stop after 20 pairs are printed. User enters Fahrenheit then the code is supposed to print out Fahrenheit plus and its Celsius counter part. It is then supposed to stop executing at 20 pairs

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int Fah, i, count = 10;
        int rows = 20;
        double Cel, uplimit, lowlimit;
        final int PER_LINE = 10;

        
        uplimit = 212;
        lowlimit = -459;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature in farenheit: ");
        Fah = scan.nextInt();
        
        //Gives error if you enter a number below -459 or aboce 212
        while (Fah < lowlimit || Fah > uplimit)
        {System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
            Fah= scan.nextInt();
        }

        //Allows for max of 20 executions of the loop
        int floop = Fah * 21;
        double loopval;
         
        for ( int n = 1 ; n <= 20 ; n = n+1 )
        {
            for (loopval = Fah; loopval < 212; loopval = loopval + 10)
            {
            // Celsius  = (Fahrenheit - 32)*5/9;
            double cloop = (loopval - 32)*5/9;
            
            DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
            System.out.println("Fareheit: " + loopval + " \t Celsius: " + fmt.format(cloop));
            
            // Print a specific number of values per line of output
            if (count % PER_LINE == 0);
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two loops, one that loops 20 times `for ( int n = 1 ; n <= 20 ; n = n+1 )`, and then you have another inner loop that runs a bunch more times for each of the previous 20 loops `for (loopval = Fah; loopval < 212; loopval = loopval + 10)`. Have a think about how you can do this with only the first loop of 20 times.

Comment: @sorifiend im not really sure. I've been trying to get this to work for hours. If I get rid of  for (loopval = Fah; loopval < 212; loopval = loopval + 10) then Fahrenheit can't go up by 10 and celsius doesn't work. If I get rid of the first loop then it still works it just loops forever. I would say get rid of the second loop but I'm not sure how to then make loopval go up by 10 every println

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander, You want the outer for to execute twenty times. But I think the initial value of Fah will determine it, as you dont want it go beyond 212 (but the discussion in comments made it clear that it can go beyond 212.)

So for example for your current code, if I give the initial value of Fah as 121 (see the output below), it execute the outer for twenty times, but inner for executes less than twenty times

I have just printed the serial number on the left to see the numbering.

```
Enter the temperature in farenheit: 121
1Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
1Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
1Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
1Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
1Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
1Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
1Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
1Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
1Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
1Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
2Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
2Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
2Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
2Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
2Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
2Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
2Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
2Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
2Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
2Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
3Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
3Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
3Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
3Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
3Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
3Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
3Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
3Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
3Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
3Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
4Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
4Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
4Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
4Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
4Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
4Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
4Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
4Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
4Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
4Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
5Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
5Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
5Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
5Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
5Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
5Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
5Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
5Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
5Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
5Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
6Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
6Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
6Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
6Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
6Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
6Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
6Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
6Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
6Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
6Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
7Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
7Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
7Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
7Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
7Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
7Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
7Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
7Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
7Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
7Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
8Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
8Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
8Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
8Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
8Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
8Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
8Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
8Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
8Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
8Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
9Fareheit: 121.0         Celsius: 49.44
9Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 55
9Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 60.56
9Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 66.11
9Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 71.67
9Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 77.22
9Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 82.78
9Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 88.33
9Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 93.89
9Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 99.44
10Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
10Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
10Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
10Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
10Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
10Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
10Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
10Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
10Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
10Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
11Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
11Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
11Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
11Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
11Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
11Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
11Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
11Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
11Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
11Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
12Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
12Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
12Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
12Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
12Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
12Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
12Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
12Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
12Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
12Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
13Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
13Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
13Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
13Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
13Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
13Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
13Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
13Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
13Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
13Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
14Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
14Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
14Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
14Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
14Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
14Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
14Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
14Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
14Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
14Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
15Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
15Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
15Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
15Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
15Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
15Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
15Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
15Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
15Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
15Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
16Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
16Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
16Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
16Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
16Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
16Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
16Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
16Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
16Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
16Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
17Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
17Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
17Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
17Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
17Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
17Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
17Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
17Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
17Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
17Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
18Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
18Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
18Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
18Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
18Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
18Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
18Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
18Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
18Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
18Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
19Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
19Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
19Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
19Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
19Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
19Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
19Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
19Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
19Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
19Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
20Fareheit: 121.0        Celsius: 49.44
20Fareheit: 131.0        Celsius: 55
20Fareheit: 141.0        Celsius: 60.56
20Fareheit: 151.0        Celsius: 66.11
20Fareheit: 161.0        Celsius: 71.67
20Fareheit: 171.0        Celsius: 77.22
20Fareheit: 181.0        Celsius: 82.78
20Fareheit: 191.0        Celsius: 88.33
20Fareheit: 201.0        Celsius: 93.89
20Fareheit: 211.0        Celsius: 99.44
```

If we modify the code as follows

```
 public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int Fah, i, count = 10;
    int rows = 20;
    double Cel, uplimit, lowlimit;
    final int PER_LINE = 10;

    
    uplimit = 212;
    lowlimit = -459;
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the temperature in farenheit: ");
    Fah = scan.nextInt();
    
    //Gives error if you enter a number below -459 or aboce 212
    while (Fah < lowlimit || Fah > uplimit)
    {System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
        Fah= scan.nextInt();
    }

    //Allows for max of 20 executions of the loop
    int floop = Fah * 21;
    double loopval = Fah;
    double cloop = 1;
     
    for ( int n = 1 ; n <= 20 ; n = n+1 )
    {
          // Celsius  = (Fahrenheit - 32)*5/9;
            cloop = (loopval - 32)*5/9;
            loopval = loopval + 10;
                          
        DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
        
        System.out.println(+ n +"Fareheit: " + loopval + " \t Celsius: " + fmt.format(cloop));
        
        // Print a specific number of values per line of output
        if (count % PER_LINE == 0);
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

It will generate the following result

```
Enter the temperature in farenheit: 121
1Fareheit: 131.0         Celsius: 49.44
2Fareheit: 141.0         Celsius: 55
3Fareheit: 151.0         Celsius: 60.56
4Fareheit: 161.0         Celsius: 66.11
5Fareheit: 171.0         Celsius: 71.67
6Fareheit: 181.0         Celsius: 77.22
7Fareheit: 191.0         Celsius: 82.78
8Fareheit: 201.0         Celsius: 88.33
9Fareheit: 211.0         Celsius: 93.89
10Fareheit: 221.0        Celsius: 99.44
11Fareheit: 231.0        Celsius: 105
12Fareheit: 241.0        Celsius: 110.56
13Fareheit: 251.0        Celsius: 116.11
14Fareheit: 261.0        Celsius: 121.67
15Fareheit: 271.0        Celsius: 127.22
16Fareheit: 281.0        Celsius: 132.78
17Fareheit: 291.0        Celsius: 138.33
18Fareheit: 301.0        Celsius: 143.89
19Fareheit: 311.0        Celsius: 149.44
20Fareheit: 321.0        Celsius: 155
```

So my answer to your question is that the repetitions of the outer for, in this case, will depend on the intial value given by the user if you consider the max limit to 212. In case there is no max limit, then this change in the code gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as mentioned in a comment, is your use of nested loops.

One possible solution is to combine them into a single loop:

```
int n;
for (n = 1, loopval = Fah; n <= 20 && loopval < 212; ++n, loopval += 10) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that actually really helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out where I was going wrong.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LaMannaAlex_Assignment2_3 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int i, count;
        double Fah=0, Cel=0, uplimit, lowlimit;
        
        
        uplimit = 212;
        lowlimit = -459;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature in farenheit: ");
        Fah = scan.nextInt();
        
        //Gives error if you enter a number below -459 or aboce 212
        while (Fah < lowlimit || Fah > uplimit)
        {System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
            Fah= scan.nextInt();
        }

        //Allows for max of 20 executions of the loop
        double loopval;
            
        
        for (count = 0; count < 20; count++)
        {
            double floop = Fah;
            // Celsius  = (Fahrenheit - 32)*5/9;
            double cloop = (floop - 32)*5/9;
            
            DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
            System.out.println("Fareheit: " + Fah + " \t Celsius: " + fmt.format(cloop));
        
            Fah=Fah+10;
                        
    
        }
    
    
    }
}
```